# pyspark - how to add a new element to ArrayType column

Tags: pyspark, pyspark-schema

````
```
ItemStruct = StructType([StructField("BomId", StringType()), StructField("price", StringType())])
BomStruct = StructType([StructField("OrderId",StringType()), StructField("items", ArrayType(ItemStruct))])
sampledata_sof = [Row("123-A", [Row("Bom-11", 120), Row("Bom-12", 140)]), Row("100-A", [Row("Bom-23", 170), Row("Bom-24", 190)])]

dfSampleBom = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(sampledata_sof), BomStruct)
dfSampleBom.printSchema() 
dfSampleBom.show()```
````

[Output from jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzBhG.png)

Question: Given the above structure, how to achieve the following? if Bom-11 is in items, add item Bom-99 (price $99).
Expected Output : Row with OrderId = 123-A should include {Bom-99, 99} in the list of items. In other words would like to generate and conditionally add one or a few elements into the items ArrayType column.

Tried using

```
    df.rdd.map(lambda x: generateItems(x))
```

but got error
*pyspark.errors.exceptions.base.PySparkRuntimeError: [CONTEXT_ONLY_VALID_ON_DRIVER] It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.*

The number of items in the df is in order of 1000s and hence would like to have a solution that can spark can natively distribute and process efficiently. (Read that UDFs may not be able to get distributed across worker nodes hence not sure if that is even an option)

Comment: take a look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_insert.html for inserting into array. or concat https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat.html if you have multiple generated items. If you want to share how you like to generate the items, it will help us understand more.

Comment: You can add with `array_insert` the `value` argument takes Col so you can pass something like `F.struct(F.col('Id').alias('name'), F.lit(100).alias('price'))`. I don't see `Events` ArrayType column in the schema, so I don't know exactly what you are trying to do here.  It is helpful if you can show us the sample inputs and expected output (toy example of your real data).

Comment: Updated the original post with an example of real data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` first to identify if `items` has `Bom-11` or not, then use `array_insert` or `concat` to insert a struct into an existing array.

#### Pyspark 3.4+

```
item_to_ingest = F.struct(F.lit('Bom-99').alias('BomId'), F.lit(99).alias('price'))

df = (dfSampleBom.select(
          'OrderId',
          F.when(F.size(F.filter('items', lambda x: x['BomId'] == 'Bom-11')) > 0, 
                 F.array_insert('items', -1, item_to_ingest))
          .otherwise(F.col('items')).alias('items')))
```

#### Pyspark 3.1+

```
item_to_ingest = F.struct(F.lit('Bom-99').alias('BomId'), F.lit(99).alias('price'))

df = (dfSampleBom.select(
          'OrderId',
          F.when(F.size(F.filter('items', lambda x: x['BomId'] == 'Bom-11')) > 0, 
                 F.concat('items', F.array(item_to_ingest)))
          .otherwise(F.col('items')).alias('items')))
```

Comment: Thanks @emma. If this needs to be recursively done for all the items that are getting added until there are no dependent items to be inserted into the array. For e.g. Bom-11 requires Bom-99 and Bom-99 requires one other item Bom-55; the dependencies are maintained in another matrix : dependencies[]. Should this be done in a UDF? Also, Can variables be passed into F.lit() like F.lit(itemId) where itemId is looked up from another data frame?

Comment: That is a different question. Please open a new one with the details.  UDF should be the last resort because it is a slow operation.